# Why "pm.newQuery(Employee.class)" and not "pm.newQuery(Employee)" in JDO?

Tags: java, jdo

In this JDO, why is `.class` needed here?

```
Query averageSalaryQuery = pm.newQuery(Employee.class);
```

I would prefer to write this more concise syntax if possible?

```
Query averageSalaryQuery = pm.newQuery(Employee);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Query averageSalaryQuery = pm.newQuery(Employee);
```

Well, it still has to be valid Java, which the above is not...

The way to refer to a class in Java is using the `.class` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Using the ".class" suffix is a convention of the language, so your second example is just semantically invalid. Nothing you can do about it really. It's equivalent to calling the `getClass()` method on an instantiation of the class, like:

```
Query averageSalaryQuery = pm.newQuery(new Employee().getClass())
```

So it's already a shortcut ;)